# Is there a better way to approximate some graphs of integrals than interpolation?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

I'm still pretty new to Mathematica so my apologies if this is a dumb question. I wanted to plot some integrals of functions for no particularly good reason, but the only decent way I could come up with to do that in Mathematica is by getting an interpolation function from a table of points generated from my original function, and then NIntegrating that interpolation function. This seems awfully fiddly. Is there a better way that I've been too dumb to notice?

Also, I wrote the "procedure" (very heavy quotes) in a block of text so I could use it later, is there a better way to write a simple program like this so that it can be called later without having to copy paste the text and run it again like I'm doing?

```
domainend = Input["Enter the maximum domain to calculate"]
iterator = Input["Enter the number of steps for each value of x in the domain."]
function = Input["Enter the function whose integral will be approximated."]
grdom1 = Input["Enter leftmost value to graph"]
grdom2 = Input["Enter rightmost value to graph"]
domainstart = (-domainend)

functionvar[x_] = 
  Interpolation[
    N[Transpose[{
      (Table[x, {x, domainstart, domainend, iterator}]), 
      (Table[function, {x, domainstart, domainend, iterator}] /. ComplexInfinity ->0)     
      }], 
    30], 
   x]
diff = NIntegrate[functionvar[x], {x, domainstart, 0}]
antiderivative[x_] = Integrate[functionvar[x], x]
f = Function[x, functionvar[x]]
i = Function[x, antiderivative[x]]
g = Function[x, antiderivative[x] - diff]

Plot[
  {f[x], g[x]}, {x, grdom1, grdom2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.0025], PlotLegends -> {function, \!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(x\)]\(function \
    \[DifferentialD]x\)\)}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, LightBlue}}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
domainend = Input["Enter the maximum domain to calculate"]
function =  Input["Enter the function whose integral will be approximated."]
grdom1 =    Input["Enter leftmost value to graph"]
grdom2 =    Input["Enter rightmost value to graph"]

Plot[{function /. x -> t, NIntegrate[function, {x, grdom1, t}]}, {t, grdom1, grdom2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.0025], Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, LightBlue}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NDSolve` to solve the integral, which will return a function you can plot.  The differential equation is the one that corresponds to an antiderivative, `a'[x] == f[x]`, with the particular one chosen such that `a[0] == 0`.

Use `Manipulate` and `InputField`s for your input.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = a[x] /.
              First @ NDSolve[{a'[x] == function, a[0] == 0}, a, {x, grdom1, grdom2}]},
  Plot[{function, sol}, {x, grdom1, grdom2}]],
 {{function, Sin[x], "function to integrate"}, InputField},
 {{grdom1, -1, "left endpoint"}, InputField},
 {{grdom2, 1, "right endpoint"}, InputField}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

---

**Update**

A simple error suppression technique: `Quiet`.  A serious error won't be caught, but many numerical functions issue warnings, that make `Manipulate` turn red.  Look into `Check` for another way to handle them.

`NDSolve` returns an `InterpolatingFunction`, which you query for its domain with `sol["Domain"]` in this case.  This one handles `Tan[x]`.  The integration stops near `π/2`, and the plot will stop there, too.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = a /.
         First @ Quiet @ NDSolve[{int'[x] == function, a[0] == 0}, a, {x, grdom1, grdom2}]},
  Plot[{function, sol[x]},
       {x, Max[grdom1, sol["Domain"][[1, 1]]], Min[grdom2, sol["Domain"][[1, 2]]]}]],
 {{function, Tan[x], "function to integrate"}, InputField},
 {{grdom1, -1, "left endpoint"}, InputField},
 {{grdom2, 5, "right endpoint"}, InputField}
 ]
```

Comment: Wow, that is much better. I can say with honesty that I have no idea how to use NDSolve. One problem with doing this is that it has a heart attack if you try to integrate Tan[x] or something similar.

Comment: @Brendan Doesn't anything fail to integrate `Tan[x]` over an asymptote?  There are ways to do error checking/catching/suppression.  You will have to work on it to make it "perfect."  See the update for a simple fix for `Tan[x]`, but a truly robust program will take considerable work.

Comment: I lazy-ed up a solution to that with my hacked together thing up there. Because I make everything into a list before integrating, I just search the list for singularities and remove them. You end up with a decent looking graph.